# c++ code convert to vb.net calculation error

Tags: c++, arrays, .net, vb.net, data-conversion

the c++ code:

```
char buffer[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 };
char* data = buffer + 4;
data = (data - buffer + 3) / 4 * 4 + buffer;
int result = data[0];
```

I convert it to vb.net

```
    Dim buffer() As Byte = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}
    Dim data() As Byte = buffer.Skip(4).ToArray()
    Dim len = (buffer.Length - data.Length + 3) \ 4 * 4
    data = buffer.Skip(len).ToArray
    Dim result As Integer = data(0)
```

Calculation results are inconsistent.
in c++ result is 5, vb.net is 8.How can I convert it correctly?

Comment: Leaving aside the nasty pointer casting, a bit of algebra tells you that `(data - buffer + 3) / 4 * 4 + buffer` is the same as `1 + buffer`, so the final `result = buffer[1]`

Comment: `data - buffer` is not even close to the same thing as `buffer.Length - data.Length`.  `data - buffer` is doing pointer arithmetic, which is something you can't even do in VB.  The operation is also not very interesting, unless there is some intervening code that might set data differently---you're computing a new offset against buffer, but one that can be computed entirely at compile-time.

Comment: The net result of the code is `int result = buffer[7]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve but, on the c++ code you are initializing a variable buffer as an array of CHAR, that means you'll convert 1 into char 1, 2 into char 2 etc... if you debug with a breakpoint you'll see that 1 will be converted into '\x1', 7 in '\a' for example... then you inizialize data as a pointer, and it points to the 5th element of buffer. Then you do something not really clear to me but it doesn't change the value of data. Then you retrieve the value of data as an int, and it's gonna be 5.

In vb.net you can't convert from char to integer and vice versa. So you can't really convert your c++ code.

Also, in the vb.net code, you inizialize buffer as an array of 16 elements, then you initialize data as an array of 12 elements, that starts from 5  (not a pointer this time). Then you inizialize len, which is gonna be 7, cause you have 16 - 12 + 3 = 7, and then you divide and multiply 7 by 4, which is gonna give you 7. Then you tell data to be again an array of bytes, but this time instead of skipping the first 4 elements of buffer, skip the first 7 (len) elements... Of course you'll get 8 as result.

If you can, please explain what you are trying to do here:

```
char* data = buffer + 4;
data = (data - buffer + 3) / 4 * 4 + buffer;
```

Because it's not very clear to me and certain operations are not possible in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Shared Function ReadDwordAlignment(m_pos As Integer) As Integer
    Dim mods As UInteger = m_pos And 3
    Dim new_pos As Integer = m_pos
    If mods <> 0 Then
        new_pos += 4 - mods
    End If
    Return new_pos - m_pos
End Function
```

Comment: update:  Math.Round(((buffer.Length - data.Length + 3) / 4)

Answer (score 0):

It's DWORD Alignment

```
 void ReadDwordAlignment() const
{
    size_t mod = (m_pos & 3);
    if (mod)
        m_pos += 4 - mod;
}
```